# Save scroll position on an android activity

Tags: android, kotlin

My main activity page can be scrolled quite a lot. My goal is to make it so when you return to the main activity, you return to the position you were in before going into another activity.

Where should I start with this? I'm very stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of [`getScrollY()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getScrollY%28%29) to read current offset and [`setScrollY()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setScrollY(int)) to resume to the required offset for your scrollable view.